# sklearn:Can't make OneHotEncoder work with Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am building a pipline for a model using ColumnTransformer.This is how my pipeline looks like,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder,OrdinalEncoder,MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

imputer_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('knn_imputer',KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5),[0,3,4,6,7])
],remainder='passthrough')

category_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ("kms_driven_engine_min_max_scaler",MinMaxScaler(),[0,6]),
    ("owner_ordinal_enc",OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['fourth','third','second','first']],handle_unknown='ignore',dtype=np.int16),[3]),
    ("brand_location_ohe",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore'),[2,5]),
],remainder='passthrough')


def build_pipeline_with_estimator(estimator):
    return Pipeline([
    ('imputer',imputer_transformer),
    ('category_transformer',category_transformer),
    ('estimator',estimator),
])
```

and this is how my dataset looks like,

```
kms_driven      owner   location    mileage     power    brand              engine  age
34000.0         first       other           NaN         12.0        Yamaha          150.0     9
28000.0         first       other           72.0         7.0         Hero                100.0    16
5947.0           first       other          53.0          19.0       Bajaj                NaN       4
11000.0         first       delhi           40.0          19.8       Royal Enfield   350.0    7
13568.0         first       delhi           63.0          14.0       Suzuki             150.0     5
```

This is how  I am using LinearRegression with my pipeline.

```
linear_regressor = build_pipeline_with_estimator(LinearRegression())

linear_regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)

print('Linear Regression Train Performance.\n')
print(model_perf(linear_regressor,X_train,y_train))

print('Linear Regression Test Performance.\n')
print(model_perf(linear_regressor,X_test,y_test))
```

Now, whenever I try to apply linear regression with the pipeline I get this error,

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'bangalore'

The 'banglore' is one of the value in the location feature, which I am trying to one-hot encode,but it is failing and I can't figure out what is going wrong here.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I have updated my question as you said.I don't have any transformed data in between the Pipeline. I am doing everything in Pipeline only. Please excuse me for my mistakes I am trying to learn these things.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I am not sure if that link is what I am looking for. One thing I want is this is the way to use OneHotEncoding with pipeline?Sklearn's doc is not very great for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After passing the imputer, the non-imputed columns are moved to the right as noted in notes under [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

> Columns of the original feature matrix that are not specified are
> dropped from the resulting transformed feature matrix, unless
> specified in the passthrough keyword. Those columns specified with
> passthrough are added at the right to the output of the transformers.

We can try just using the imputer first:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

imputer_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('knn_imputer',KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5),[0,3,4,6,7])
],remainder='passthrough')
```

We can try it with an example data and you will see your categorical columns are now shifted right:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'kms':[0,1,2],'owner':['first','first','second'],
'location':['other','other','delhi'],'mileage':[9,8,np.nan],
'power':[3,2,1],'brand':['A','B','C'],'engine':[10,100,1000],'age':[3,4,5]})

imputer_transformer.fit_transform(X_train)
Out[25]: 
array([[0.0, 9.0, 3.0, 10.0, 3.0, 'first', 'other', 'A'],
       [1.0, 8.0, 2.0, 100.0, 4.0, 'first', 'other', 'B'],
       [2.0, 8.5, 1.0, 1000.0, 5.0, 'second', 'delhi', 'C']], dtype=object)
```

In your case, you can see the `engine` column is now the fourth column, and your ordinal is the fifth, categorical last two, so a simple solution might be:

```
category_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ("kms_driven_engine_min_max_scaler",MinMaxScaler(),[0,3]),
    ("owner_ordinal_enc",OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['fourth','third','second','first']],
handle_unknown='ignore',dtype=np.int16),[5]),
    ("brand_location_ohe",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore'),[6,7]),
],remainder='passthrough')

y_train = [7,3,2]

linear_regressor = build_pipeline_with_estimator(LinearRegression())

linear_regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination.Now I understood where I am making the mistake. Once again I really appreciate your effort.